# Accessing a variable in a nested Angular foreach loop using context

Tags: angularjs

I'm still brand new to Angular and Javascript, looked around for a solution to this but having a hard time finding one so please bear with me here. I have an Angular function that looks like this:

```
post: function(url, params) {

var someObject = {
    'key': ['value1', 'value2']
}

for (var paramKey in params) {
    angular.forEach(someObject, function (values, key) {
        if (paramKey.indexOf(key) !== -1) {
            debugger; // params is still defined here

            angular.forEach(values, function (innerValue) {
                if (paramKey.indexOf(innerValue) !== -1) {
                    debugger; // params is no longer defined
                }
            }, params)
        }
    }, params)
}
```

I want to iterate through some keys and values and based on what I find in the inner loop, I want to manipulate the `params` object before sending it to the API.

Looking at the [forEach documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach), I can use the `context` argument to pass the object inside the forEach and keep it in scope. However, I'm using a nested loop, and for some reason it seems I can't keep passing `params` via `context` through into the nested loop. It just becomes `undefined` the second time.

How can I access and manipulate the `params` object in the inner loop?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting loops is always best to be avoided, so I kind of thought, why do you even need to itterate if you are just checking the key of the object and then check if the key matches any of array strings. You can do the same thing like this:

```
post: (url, params) => {
    var someObject = {
            'key': ['value1', 'value2']
    }
        Object.values(params).forEach((paramKey) => {
            if(someObject[paramKey]) {
                if(someObject[paramKey].includes(paramKey)) {

                }
            } 
        })
    }
```